# WPF DataGrid is not initialized before hooking event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, itemssource

I've got a simple property getter which returns whatever datagrid is curretly selected within a TabbedPanel

```
    private DataView ActiveGrid
    {
        get 
        {
            switch (TabPanel.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0: return (DataView)Grid1.ItemsSource;
                case 1: return (DataView)Grid2.ItemsSource;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But when I try to invoke it like this

```
    private void TabPanel_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        updateIndex("{0} Items", ActiveGrid.Count);
    }
```

it throws an `InvokationTargetException` with an inner `NullReferenceException`. So the ItemsSource is not initialized? Hmm..? Because in my `MainWindow` constructor I set the ItemsSource like so `Grid1.ItemsSource = myDataTable();`

My XAML looks like this

```
    <TabControl x:Name="TabPanel" 
                Margin="0,155,0,28"
                SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="TabPanel_SelectionChanged">
        <TabItem x:Name="Grid1Tab" Header="Grid1" >
            <DataGrid x:Name="Grid1"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      Background="#FFE5E5E5" 
                      ColumnWidth="*"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="Grid2Tab" Header="Grid2">
            <DataGrid x:Name="Grid2"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      Background="#FFE5E5E5"
                      ColumnWidth="*"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: @HighCore - wow, what a poor comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
private DataView ActiveGrid
{
    get 
    {
        if (TabPanel.IsInitialized)
        {
            switch (TabPanel.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0: return (DataView)Grid1.ItemsSource;
                case 1: return (DataView)Grid2.ItemsSource;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

in the Above code, you have checked the **if (TabPanel.IsInitialized)**. The problem is with `TabControl`.. it will not be Initialized in the `Ctor`... so the getter returns `null` and you got the error..

Comment: That's legacy code and is no longer there. I will update my original question.

Comment: is the TabPanel is Loaded?